How to modify http-proxy-middleware TLS fingerprint?
I use http-proxy-middleware to access various web-sites, including those having TLS fingerprint checks. My problem is that the proxy's TLS fingerprint is not corresponding to the User-Agent header I'm passing, that's why my visits are sometimes being rejected by antibot protection. Is there a way to make http-proxy-middleware reveal only specific things I want during TLS handshake?
If there are no workarounds for http-proxy-middleware, could you please recommend a proxy tool for NodeJS that could be configured in such a way?

the proxy's TLS fingerprint is not corresponding to the User-Agent header I'm passing ... can you explain what 'TLS fingerprint' means to you and how the User-Agent header is involved in it?

@PresidentJamesK.Polk - Let me explain my logic. Each client has its own TLS features that can be used to make a fingerprint. For example, Chrome installed in my PC has TLS 1.1 and 1.0 enabled by default, while they are disabled in my Firefox (I'm using https://browserleaks.com/tls for reference). http-proxy-middleware client has its own characteristics. So basically you can compare User Agents (with some other data) and their known default SSL/TLS capabilites set by the vendor to tell whether they match a general pattern (used widely) or not.
